Trait bound does not propagate to sub traits
I would expect the code example below to work since the bound on trait C has an implicit bound, through Bs bound on A::I, on I being Copy. It doesn't work though and I'm trying to understand why. I have read through the reference on traits and on bounds but there is nothing there that helps me understand why the snipped below won't compile.
trait A {
    type I;
}

trait B where Self: A, <Self as A>::I: Copy {
}

trait C where Self: B {
}

Link to playground
This Works:
trait A {
    type I;
}

trait B: A<I: Copy> {
}

trait C: B {
}

but I don't understand the difference.

Perhaps you want something like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f04d831ad7ff3d2ff7dbe136e218024f ?

Yes, that works. But I don't understand the difference.

Looks like this syntax does not mean what you believe it means... But I don't know what it means either :D Let's wait for some experts.

This issue should explain the problem: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/20671
